# array session object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using session objects in C# ASP.net.

I like to know whether I can declare and use an array of such objects.

For example assume there is a session object "User", then I say:

```
User[,] u_sers_ = User[3,4].GetCurrentUser;
```

What I am trying to do is declare an array of session objects, is this possible?

If it is not possible, how do I declare an array of object "members"?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing in your code above involves any `Session` object. You may have some terminology confusion, here:

The object named `Session` is a member variable of the `Page` instance object, among others. It is there as a convenience to refer to *the* session object for the current user session. You do not do anything to create an 'array' of these objects - there is only one per-user-session currently active, and each `Page` and other similar object can only deal with the current one.

You put objects in the Session dictionary to use them. Again; this is a single object, automatically created and scoped per-session for you. You do not create it. But you do create individual objects to insert into the `Session` object, and it stores them for you, keeping track of which `Session` collection is attached to which session.

You could certainly put an array of something in the `Session` dictionary, but I don't think that's really what you are looking for here.

---

**Edit** Session usage:

In one page, you can add things to your `Session` object:

```
UserObject user = new UserObject(Request);
Session["user"] = user;
int[] integerValues = {1, 4, 6, 7, 44, 334, 3984};
Session["integers"] = integerValues;
object otherStuff = new object();
Session["other"] = otherStuff;
```

Then you can refer to those object by their name, after testing to make sure they really do exist and casting them properly. You *always* must test that the object exists, because the Session could expire at any time.

```
UserObject user = Session["user"] as UserObject;
if(user!=null)
    ...do stuff here...
int[] integerValues = Session["integers"] as int[];
if(integerValues!=null)
    ...do stuff here...
etc...
```

Comment: Thanks, let's say I have the following as a session member:         public string Trip_Name
        {
            get { return _Trip_Name; }
            set { _Trip_Name = value; }
        }     How do I make this as an array?

Comment: You don't add members to `Session`; you add objects to its Dictionary. I'll demonstrate with an edit to my answer.